# How to declare variables in a query, in a PHP function

Tags: php, mysql, variables

I'm struggling for a few days now with this query.
I assume this is really simple, but I can´t see what I'm doing wrong.

I'm using a "functions.php" file where I save all my queries, each one within its own PHP function, something like:

```
$query ='
    SELECT *
    FROM Table
';
```

I now would like to be able to use variables in my queries, declaring them within the query it self. Something like:

```
$query ='
    SET @myvar := 0
    SELECT ID, @myvar := @myvar + SomeRow AS Result
    FROM Table
';
```

I've been googling and searching in SO, found many solutions but can't make any of them work... I for sure missing something.

Any advise is welcome...

Thank you

Comment: I'm not sure what you really try to achieve. Can you explain that to us?

Comment: My objective is to be able to build a query that sums the current row value to the previous one, so if I have a row with the values (1, 2, 3, 4), the result should be (1, 3, 6, 10).

Comment: You need to provide more info / better explanation. Just guessing, but your issue is either with [php variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) within your functions **or** with trying to execute 2 queries in your `$query` when all functions other than `mysqli_multi_query()` will only execute 1 query statement.

Comment: Am I wrong assuming I can use variables directly into mySQL? I'm not speaking about PHP variable (like $myvar) but actual mySQL variables built into my query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That are two Question (Querys) . So you must separete it.

```
$query ='
    SET @myvar := 0;
    SELECT ID, @myvar := @myvar + SomeRow AS Result
    FROM Table;
';
```

**or you init it so**

```
$query ='
    SELECT ID, @myvar := @myvar + SomeRow AS Result
    FROM Table, (SELECT @myvar := 0) AS init
';
```

**a Sample**

```
MariaDB [test]> select id, order_ID from orders limit 10;
+-----+----------+
| id  | order_ID |
+-----+----------+
| 632 |      111 |
| 633 |      111 |
| 634 |      111 |
| 635 |      112 |
| 636 |      113 |
| 637 |      113 |
| 638 |      113 |
| 639 |      113 |
| 640 |      113 |
| 641 |      113 |
+-----+----------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [test]> SELECT id, @myvar := @myvar + order_ID
    -> FROM orders, (SELECT @myvar := 0) AS init LIMIT 10;
+-----+-----------------------------+
| id  | @myvar := @myvar + order_ID |
+-----+-----------------------------+
| 632 |                         111 |
| 633 |                         222 |
| 634 |                         333 |
| 635 |                         445 |
| 636 |                         558 |
| 637 |                         671 |
| 638 |                         784 |
| 639 |                         897 |
| 640 |                        1010 |
| 641 |                        1123 |
+-----+-----------------------------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Just tried both queries.
The 1º one does'nt work.
The 2º Works like a charm.

I understand what you did... simple and clean... should have thought about it ;)

Comment: @Vicente Chazard - i have also tried both and it works. if "SomeRow" not numeric ?

Comment: @Vicente Chazard - i have add a sample in my answer

Comment: For some reason if  I use the SET before the SELECT my query breaks

Comment: if you use mysql and not mysqli you can only do one query in a call